# The doubling constant in a metric measure space is 1 iff $|X|$=1

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

So, in a paper I'm reading, it is stated that

> One can easily check, unless the metric space reduces
> to a singleton, that $C_{(X,d)} > 1$

Where $C_{(X,d)}$ is defined as the infimum of doubling constants (any Borel regular measure is valid) in a metric space $(X,d)$. For a little bit more of context, a doubling constant in a metric measure space $(X,d, \mu)$ is a number $C_{\mu}$ such that $\mu(B(x, 2r))\leq C_{\mu}\mu(B(x,r))$ for every $x$ in $X$ and $r>0$.

I clearly get the intuition of why this must be true: if there is more than one element in the space, there must be balls which are "bigger" according to the measure than others because of the additivity of the measure, and hence the doubling constant can't be one. Anyway, I'm having trouble to actually write a proof, and specially to deal with that infimum. Any ideas?

Comment: Chapter 1 of Stein's Harmonic Analysis deals with those issues.

Comment: @OliverDíaz thanks, looks like this source could help me, but still it deals only with metrics and measures in R^n. This is supposed to be a more general result including discrete spaces, etc.